# Where does the word "valuable" fit best?

Tags: word-choice, grammar, word-usage, syntactic-analysis

Which sentence sounds better or correct ?

> 1. I have acquired many characteristics that will play a valuable role in my profession.
> 2. I have acquired many characteristics that will be valuable in my profession.

Comment: Aren't there a resume writing help/books/forums all over the web? Otherwise this is going to be a very slow process, sentence by sentence.

Comment: If you must use one of those sentences, use #2. "Play a valuable role" is an obnoxious verbosity better replaced by "will be valuable". There's no need for the cliched acting metaphor of "play a valuable role".

Answer (score 1):

This has to be "opinion only".

Neither sounds marvellous to me.
 I'd look for something more like

- "I have acquired many professionally valuable characteristics"

and even that I like less than I'd like to like it.

Both examples have a "forward looking" and "not there yet" feeling.
 They present more as
"I have been learning a lot and I expect the knowledge to be useful in future"
rather than
"my current incredible levels of competence and omniscience are due to years of practical experience and real-world learning."

I'm not suggesting you actually say it that way :-).

Comment: I definitely see what you're talking about with the "not there yet" feeling. Thank you!